# 1976 peugeot 10-speed bike correct tire pressure?

Tags: tire, safety

I have a 1976 peugeot 10-speed bike. What is the correct tire pressure? I ride over concrete sidewalks and rough, pitted asphalt roads and paths.

Comment: What width are the tires?

Comment: The tire more determines than the bike.  It should state a pressure on the side wall.

Comment: How old are the tyres?

Comment: Age of the bike has little to do with the pressure needed. Tires (size and maximum pressure) and to a limited extent rims, dictate the pressure to run

Comment: The rider's weight will also factor into it.

Comment: Voting to leave open, because while its opinion, its also totally within reason to suggest a figure and why, or to suggest how to estimate a starting value and then fine-tune from there.

Comment: @Criggie but there is no opinion or starting figure to give.  He very well could have a tire rated for 40 psi, or just as easily one rated for 200 psi.  Neither are likely, and for most road bikes, what comes with them is somewhere between 70-90 psi, but as long as we are working with facts and not speculation, it's easier to tell the OP to look at their tire.

Comment: Read what it says on the sidewall!!  (Note that the pressure you're running is almost certainly too low.)

Answer (score 2):

First, and especially with a tire that old, check it for wear.  If it's cracked and dry-rotted, replace it.  If there are visible rips in the sidewall, also replace it.  If neither of those are the case, look at the sidewall of the tire.  Most tires should have a PSI recommendation molded in the rubber of the sidewall somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the tire is in good condition, else it should be replaced. The pressure for the tire can be calculated with this tool (see [Link](http://www.dorkypantsr.us/bike-tire-pressure-calculator.html)). Also when you purchase a quality tire there should be a guide delivered with it that tells the pressure based on the weight of you + bike.

There are several other factors you want to take into account.

- The pressure on the tire is the **maximum** pressure you can go lower as that.
- You and only you can determinate the most comfort/effective pressure for the tire. For example Paris Rouxbais riders all have different pressure in their tires, some even have different pressure at the front and rear. Based on their own experience and comfort. Same goes for cyclo cross riders.

Comment: "harder = better" has been discussed and measured and has been found to be false.

Comment: It is my personal opinion as I stated. Look at the tire for the pressure is worst thing said on this topic. All is relative to the tire type.. Tubeless with 10bar will feel softer then tire with inner tire with 7bar pressure.

Comment: I know, it's just that your personal opinion contradicts facts.

Comment: In my personal experience as road cyclist from age of 14 to 23 (quited as my U23 career ended and did not manage to get a contract). I had a base pressure that was good for me and after the recon I would tell the mechanic based on the road that was a head keep the base pressure, increase the pressure or decrease the pressure. And this is how I learned it in the circuit. If you ride on a smooth race track harder = better simple as that.

Comment: This edited version is far better. The thing is, if the ground is not completely smooth and your tires don't absorb it, you'll get worse losses somewhere else.